# Python33, Flask: Lot of Errors starting Hello World

Tags: python, windows, flask

I just have installed with pip flask and HTML5 on my window-sytem. When I start the Hello World!-program with IDLE I get the text correct in a new tab of Firefox. But also a lot of error-messages in the Python shell:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1519, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__path__'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\utils.py", line 18, in <module>
        from html.entities import name2codepoint
    ImportError: No module named 'html.entities'; html is not a package

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Users/Public/python/testflask.py", line 13, in <module>
        from flask import Flask
      File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\flask\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
        from werkzeug.exceptions import abort
      File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\__init__.py", line 154, in <module>
        __import__('werkzeug.exceptions')
      File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\exceptions.py", line 71, in <module>
        from werkzeug.wrappers import Response
      File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\wrappers.py", line 36, in <module>
        from werkzeug.utils import cached_property, environ_property, \
      File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\utils.py", line 20, in <module>
        from htmlentitydefs import name2codepoint
    ImportError: No module named 'htmlentitydefs'
```

Help! Help! Help!

Comment: Do you have a local directory or file with the name `html` or `html.py`?

Comment: Yes:  c:\users\surfkonto\pictures\aldi bestellsoftware\html

Comment: And is that directory *on your Python path*; e.g. is `c:\users\surfkonto\pictures\aldi bestellsoftware` in `sys.path` or your current working directory?

Comment: Put `import html; print(html)` at the top of your Flask file and see what is printed. *Rename that directory or file* if this is not located in `C:\Python33\lib\`.

Comment: I get printed: <module 'html' from 'C:/Users/Public/python\\html.py'>

Comment: Bingo, rename that file.

Comment: I have renamed the File, but the errors are the same after the outprint : <module 'html' from 'C:/Users/Public/python\\html.py'>

Comment: Is there also a `html.pyc` file in the same location? If so, delete that.

Comment: Thank you very much! It's running correctly.

Comment: It's running, but now I get no output in a Firefox tab

Comment: That'd be a *new and different* problem. :-)

Comment: thank you @MartijnPieters I had my file as html.py and that was causing the problem. I was cursing myself for 1 hour before I saw this

Answer (score 2):

You have a *local* `html.py` module or `html` package that is masking the built-in library. Rename it, as it is breaking software that relies on the standard library version.

You can find what file you need to rename or move aside with:

```
import html
print(html)
```

Rename that file to something else. Take into account that there might be a `.pyc` file as well; remove the `.pyc` bytecode cache altogeher if present.

Comment: Dear Martijn, the answer in the shell is

Comment: <module 'html' from 'C:\\Python33\\lib\\html\\__init__.py'>
     * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/

Comment: Sorry, I make a lot of mistakes myself:

Comment: @user3891230: now that you removed the other file, you no longer need the import or the `print(html)` line. If you have *new* problems, ask *new* questions.